# How to check if current logged user is author of post

Tags: php, wordpress, twig, timber

Im new to Timber/Twig.
I want to display "edit button" near posts that already logged in user is author of (wordpress).

Im using loop to display posts, if I use `{{user.id}` and `{{post.author.id}}` i get current user ID and ID of posts author.

How can I use conditional to display button near posts that current user is author of?
I tried to use `{% if user.id == post.author.id %}` but It doesn't work. I tried to replace `==` with `===`.
Do you have any idea?

---

```
<?php  
    use Timber\PostQuery;
    use Timber\Timber;
    $context = Timber::context();
    $context['posts'] = Timber::get_posts(['post_type'=>'product']);
    Timber::render('templates/pages/my-yachts-product.twig', $context);
```

```
<div class="product__buttons flex items-center justify-end flex-wrap">
    {% include "templates/atoms/button.twig" with {title: __('Details', 'empressia'), url: product.link, class: 'btn--medium'} %}
    {% if user.id == post.author.id %}
    <a href="http://localhost/ansebsail/edit-yacht/?post={{ product.id }}" class="btn btn--medium"> Edytuj </a>
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

EDIT - Function that I use to loop "products" which are modified posts

```
 function FilterPostsAjax()
  {
    $response = [
      'html' => '',
      'description' => '',
      'total_posts' => 0
    ];

    $posts_query = $_POST;
    $posts_query = $this->formatQuery($posts_query);
    $wpQuery = new PostQuery($posts_query);
    $response['query'] = $posts_query;
    $response['total_posts'] = $wpQuery->found_posts;
    $response['pagination'] = Timber::compile('components/pagination/pagination.twig',  ['pagination' => (array)$wpQuery->pagination(5)]);


    $posts = $wpQuery->get_posts();

    $context = Timber::context();

    $countPosts = count($posts);

    if ($countPosts) {
      $context['layout'] = 'wide';

      foreach ($posts as $post) {
        $context['product'] = $post;
    
        if (isset($posts_query['is_favourites']) && $posts_query['is_favourites']) {
          $context['is_favourites'] = true;
        }

  $response['html'] .= Timber::compile("templates/molecules/product.twig", $context);

      }
    }
 echo json_encode($response);
    die();
  }
```

Comment: can you post the actual loop code?

Comment: wondering if you need to change `post.author.id` to `product.author.id`?  This is just based on seeing `product.link` and `product.id`...

Comment: Also are you sure `author` is part of the timber/twig context?

Comment: [Yes it is](https://timber.github.io/docs/reference/timber-user/)

Comment: What @mikerojas said. What is in the for-loop around your template? `{% for product in posts %}`? Is so then you should use `product.author.id`

Comment: Okay but i get good id's of user and author with user.id and post.author.id, my problem is if i can do something like if user.id == post.author.id -> then show a href.

Comment: That's because the `post` variable will be defined as well. Please provide the for-loop around your template

Comment: Okay thats reasonable, u were right using product.author.id == user.id works for me, I added loop function if someone encounter similar problem in future, thanks for help!